# Postgresql - Changing or Reversing the Numbers into a new column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way in postgresql where I can reverse the highest integer number (aka version number) and replacing it with the lowest? Reverse it and then create a new column where it shows the reverse order. As a side note, the highest integer number could be different such as it could be 4 (as the example below), or it could be 40. At the same time, keeping the version # the same if there are multiples. Like if there are two 40, they version will be the same to the new number and not part of a count.  As an example:

```
  software| version #
( 18.0    |     4     )
( 18.0    |     4     )
( 17.0    |     3     )
( 17.0    |     3     )
( 16.0    |     2     )
( 16.0    |     2     )
( 16.0    |     2     )
( 15.0    |     1     )
```

And change it to:

```
 software | New vers #
( 18.0    |     1     )
( 18.0    |     1     )
( 17.0    |     2     )
( 17.0    |     2     )
( 16.0    |     3     )
( 16.0    |     3     )
( 16.0    |     3     )
( 15.0    |     4     )
```

Here was my failed attempt:

```
select
    tx.cid,
    count(camaversion)
FROM 
    (select 
        software, 
        version 
      from  
        software_info  
        GROUP BY 
            software_info.software, 
            version 
        Order by version desc )tx
    Group by tx.software, tx.version
```

Still trying to understand the full capabilities of postgresql and the code has been haunting my brain and cannot seem to figure out.  I just know there is a way. Trying to fit this onto a map so there is a easier way to color code it. Any code or suggestions will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select si.*, dense_rank() over (order by version desc) as new_version
from software_info si;
```

Comment: It works great, but a follow up question.   How would put null to last number.

Comment: Ok I think I got this figured out.  Thank you for suggesting dens_rank() over.  It works.  Just had to add COALESCE() into for the nulls.  Works like a charm. Here is the update version:

Comment: select si.*, dense_rank() over (order by COALESCE(version,0) desc) as new_version from software_info si;

Comment: @NicholasCAMAvision . . . You would add `NULLS LAST` to the `ORDER BY`:  `dense_rank() over (order by version desc nulls last)`.